# Can't import a script into another script

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to share a script between other script. But I can't import it in those scripts. If I use

```
const { lists } = require("../assets/listManager.js");
```

it gives me

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
> and when I try

```
import{ lists } from "../assets/listManager.js";
```

I get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

How do I use listManager.js in other scripts?

Comment: export const lists ='.........'

Comment: If you just want to refer to methods and variables from listManager.js then you don't need to import the script, as long as both listManager.js and main script file are imported in the page... what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: if you work without any transpiler like `Babel` and use it in the browser make sure that you add `type="module"` in your main script tag

Comment: @Kedar I want to share an array between multiple script. So they all can modify the array

Comment: @JosephI don't use Babel. It's an Electron application so it runs in Node I guess

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the script that's doing the importing doesn't have node integration enabled and is running in a renderer process. If you want node integration, you'd need to enable it in the window that hosts that script `new BrowserWindow({ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true })`.

Otherwise, you can't import thing into the script, You'll have to use a preload script to expose the APIs that you care about to your script, preferably with `contextIsolation` enabled. See [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation)